# Can I return a Date object from a JAX-RS call?

Tags: java, jax-rs

Why is it so hard to get this right? I want to serialize a date object returned from my JAX-RS endpoint.

If I wrap the Date object inside a class and provide an `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` to serialize the object, it works fine. Please tell me there is a better/easier way.

This code doesn't work -

```
   @POST
   @Consumes("application/xml")
   @Path("/foo")
   public Date someMethodThatReturnsDate(SomeObject obj) {
    Date d = someService.getDate(obj);
    return d;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and it was because of `java.sql.Date`, you should use `java.util.Date` instead.